# How to do CamelCase with German words (or with any other language that supports compound nouns)?

Tags: c#, language-agnostic, localization, naming-conventions

*Disclaimer: Feel free to close this as "too localized", if you think it is inappropriate for StackOverflow. Since there's quite a large German-speaking community here, I thought I'd give it a try.*

CamelCase is used frequently in programming language conventions (method names in C#, public method names in Java, etc.). It's quite easy to do in English: You just concatenate the words and capitalize the first letter of each one: `DisplayName`, `InternalName`.

German, however, supports *compound nouns* in many cases. E.g., "**Anzeigename**" (`DisplayName`) is a single noun, but "**interner Name**" (`InternalName`) is not. So, the latter case is easy to camelify: It's `InternerName`, just like the CamelCase rules in English. What about the first case? One could

- use `Anzeigename`, to keep consistent with German grammar, or
- use `AnzeigeName`, to keep consistent with the look and feel of CamelCase and with other `*Name`-s, which are not single nouns.

Is there some guideline or well-established best practice on this?

I realize that just using English names solves this problem quite easily, but that's sometimes not feasible when developing domain-specific software, or when configuration files must be human-readable by people without good English language skills. It just doesn't make sense to make up an English translation for *Umsatzsteuervoranmeldung*, when you are certain that the software will only be used in a German language context...

Comment: *Argh.* Please do not use [denglish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denglisch) in code. `if (Anzeige) then Aufruf()` is *extremely* irritating.

Comment: IME it is best to find english words, I'd only use a localized word if there is no direct equivalent.

Comment: I agree that it's a nuisance. Still, there are situations where no English equivalent exists or where an English equivalent would appear very out-of-place or artificial. In these cases, the problem illustrated above arises. In fact, in these cases, it might make sense to use German for *all* words, to be at least consistent in this regard.

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the same problem in English too.

For example **Surname** versus **LastName**

Use a captial if when written in the language there would be a preceding space

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any reason why you would camelcase names to be "conformant". Norwegian (my native language) works the same way and camelcase should not be for anything else except a replacement for blanks.

But then again, I would never write code in anything except English.